# Ionic, HTML in array

Tags: html, arrays, angular, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic/Angular.
I need to print an array with some HTML in it

```
{
"code" : "06",
"descr" : "Some text:</br>Other text.<br/>Other text</br>Other text."
}
```

But it doesn't go to a new line, it prints even the  tag in my page instead.
There's a way to avoid this?

I've read something about ng-bind-html-unsafe but apparently has been removed from angular.

Comment: maybe ng-bind-html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `innerHtml`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of yourArray">
    <div [innerHTML]="item.descr"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @downvoter what's reason to downvote? It would be really helpful to me to improve my answer

Comment: @WilliamManzato I am glad to help you!:)